# Can't get qutebrowser caret/visual mode to work

Tags: browser

I can't find any documentation of `qutebrowser`s caret mode.
I thought I would be able to search for a phrase with `/`, press `v`, extend the selection as far as needed with normal motion commands, e.g. `j$`, and the `y`ank.  But once in caret mode, nothing happens, motion commands have no effect.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running with `--backend webengine`? Caret mode [doesn't work yet](https://github.com/The-Compiler/qutebrowser/issues/666#issuecomment-259496998).

Comment: @jasonwryan, oh.  any idea when it will? will it be safe to run without in a firejail?

Comment: No. If you weigh the risk of running the webengine without caret mode, versus the gaping hole that is webkit, doing without caret mode seems like a pretty good tradeoff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jasonwryan mentioned, caret mode doesn't work with QtWebEngine yet. Someone is working on porting [this Chromium addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/caret-browsing/fklpgenihifpccgiifchnihilipmbffg) to qutebrowser, but I'm not sure how ready it is.